# Why is Django not loading my template view but it once was? I included my template code

Tags: django

My view was running fine until Ill tried to override an admin view. Which i eventually got to work. However in the process I broke the path to my view that was working.  The admin view had nothing to do with my originally working view.

Now I copied my view into every possible level of my project structure. Yet the django template loader fails to find my order_input.html

The error shows the correct path to my order_input.html. I made copies of order_input.html at every single possible level of my project... but django still cant find it.

APP - URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hw/$', views.helloworld, name='helloworld'),
    url(r'^order_input/$', views.order_input, name='order_input'),
    url(r'^time/$', views.today_is, name='time'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

SETTINGS.PY

```
    # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'import_export',
    'hw_app',
]
```

PROJECT URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('r', include('hw_app.urls')),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('clearfile', views.clearfile),
    path('readfile', views.readfile),
    path('writefile', views.writefile),
    path('helloworld', views.helloworld),
    path('order_input', views.order_input),
    path('ajax_view', views.ajax_view),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order_input url defined in both your project and your app urls.py files, only in the hw_app version it has a trailing slash. The slashless project URL may be looking in the wrong places for things as it will assume there is a related view at its level.

Try removing that path from the project urls.py file. Assuming it should be going to the same place, it's already included when you include(hw_apps.urls) (as url() is just a more up-to-date path() ).  Then try calling the page with a trailing slash.

The only view file then relevant should be hw_apps/views.py. For consistency place the HTML template file is in  hw_app/templates/hw_app/order_input.html so you know django should be able to find it.

Comment: SamSparx, Thankyou for your answer...  I did remove the path from the project level. Everything is working as expected.